# Hardy–Littlewood maximal function – an example

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $$f(x)= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x\log^2x}, & \text{if} \hspace{2mm} 0 < x < \frac{1}{2}\\
0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

I have so far shown that $f$ is integrable. However, I am confused on this step in the book showing that the [maximal function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_maximal_function) $M(f)$ is not integrable.

$$ M f(x) \geqslant \frac{1}{2x} \int\limits_0^{2x} |f(y)|\, {\rm d}y$$

Where is the $\frac{1}{2x}$ coming from and why are the limits in the integral now $0$ and $2x$. I would appreciate clarification and motivation for this.

Comment: what is "the maximal function"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_maximal_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming $x > 0$ here. They're taking the average of $|f|$ over the interval centered at $x$ of radius $x$. This interval is exactly $[0,2x]$. So the average of $|f|$ over this interval is given by
$${1 \over 2x} \int_0^{2x} |f(y)| \, dy$$
The maximal function $Mf(x)$ is the supremum of the average of $|f|$ over all intervals centered at $x$, so it is at least this large.